# How to authenticate on internet explorer using CORS is there any extenstion?

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I am authenticating through CORS extenstion on chrome and mozilla but on Internet Explorer 11 and edge I cant find any extension can someone help me is there any way to do this ..?

Tried searching extenstions for CORS but didnt find

I need to be able to login and the data to come on IE

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this kind of extension for Edge or IE before. To enable cross-origin requests in FireFox, Safari, Chrome and IE 10 and later. You could refer to [this article](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests) and [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to attach the following headers to all responses:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://webdavserver.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DAV, content-length, Allow
```